# How to print from a windows web server to a local thermal printer

Tags: .net-core, printing, thermal-printer, epson

I'am in a situation where my client wants to print order receipts automatically from it's website.
He has an Epson TM-T88VI. His website is hosted on a Windows webserver. Does anyone has experience with similar cases?

I've tried to build it with some nuget packages and it only works in develop mode because the printer is in the samen network.

For now I've build it with a separate electron app in node js installed on his desktop but we are facing too much issues with it.

Comment: Why print from a web server? If the printer in question is locally connected to the client computer, wouldn't it be possible to print from an application running on the client? If there are any conditions or restrictions that require direct cooperation between the web server and local printer, it would be a good idea to add those details. However, there is a method like this, which may be helpful. [ReceiptLine](https://www.npmjs.com/package/receiptline), [ReceiptLine を使って Web アプリケーションからレシート・ラベルシールを印刷する](https://qiita.com/yamukotonaku/items/53f3fa167ca7c867c4b4)